# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'api.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Having a hard time understanding why I am receiving this error. If I just leave the api/user/ path it works fine but when I try to add api/user/date_counter/ path I get this error. Using Django 3. Any help would be appreciated.

Pseudo-graphics like below is based on how maven shows the output of dependency:tree command.

In my experience it has been easy to read and type. It naturally matches tree-like file structure:

```
Backend
 |
 +-- api
 |  |
 |  +-- urls.py
 |  |
 |  +-- settings.py
 |    
 +-- date_counter
 |  |  
 |  +-- urls.py
 |    
 +-- user
 |  |  
 |  +-- urls.py
```

date_counter/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from date_counter import views

app_name = 'date_counter'

urlpatterns = [
    path('date_counter/', views.DateCounterViewSet.as_view(), name='date_counter'),
]
```

date_counter/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from date_counter.models import Date_Counter
from date_counter.serializers import DateCounterSerializer

class DateCounterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Date_Counter.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DateCounterSerializer
```

date_counter/serializers.py

```
from date_counter.models import Date_Counter
from rest_framework import serializers

class DateCounterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class meta:
        model = Date_Counter
        fields = ['user', 'date', 'count']
```

date_counter/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from user.models import User

class Date_Counter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

api/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/user/', include('user.urls')),
    path('api/user/date_counter/', include('date_counter.urls')),
]
```

user/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from knox.views import LogoutView
from user import views

app_name = 'user'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.RegisterUserView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', views.LoginUserView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('user/', views.UserView.as_view(), name='user'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox_logout'),
    path('registersuperuser/', views.RegisterSuperUserView.as_view(), name='register_super_user'),
    path('all/', views.AllUsersView.as_view(), name='all'),
]
```

api/settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'knox',
    'user',
    'date_counter',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',),
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'api.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'api.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'
```

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 590, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/francisco_navarro/.local/share/virtualenvs/pomodoro_tracker-2HYScThJ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 597, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'api.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Comment: Paste your whole settings.py and folder structure/file organization

Comment: Included all settings.py and folder structure

Comment: Have you tried commenting out each URL one by one?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how you registering your ViewSet to `urlpatterns`. Try like this:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('date_counter', views.DateCounterViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

More information can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/).

Comment: What's weird is that I also tried the view with generics.ListAPIView as I also thought it could be something with how ViewSets are configured but was still getting the error

Comment: as the error suggested, their is a circular import. please share your user models and views

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the `date_counter/views.py` file was missing an import from django rest framework, `from rest_framework import viewsets`.